# How to add signature to Preview on a Mac Mini?

Tags: preview, mac-mini, signature

How can I add my signature to Preview on a Mac without a built-in camera?

I've got a mid 2012 Mac mini, running macOS 10.11 using a 3rd party mouse and Apple keyboard, connected to 2x 3rd party HDMI displays.

I want to add my signature to the Preview app, so that I can sign documents digitally in Preview without having to print, sign, scan.

In the past I have used a built-in webcam to get my signatures saved into Preview, but I can't do that on this Mac mini.

I have access to another mac with a camera and an iPhone if required.

Comment: This question differs from the marked duplicate. Unlike the duplicate, this question does not assume the availability of another Mac with a camera.

Comment: @GrahamMiln raises a good point. Can you clarify whether you do or do not have access to another Mac with an iSight camera (or other webcam)? Also, since you're not wanting to print, sign or scan, can we assume you're happy with using a camera of some sort (e.g. an iPhone)? Clarifying these points would help a Mod or the community determine if this question is or isn't a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: @GrahamMiln  question updated to reflect the above comments